# Change wallpaper programmatically in KDE

Tags: dbus, kde-plasma, qdbus

I'd like to write a program in F# to change the wallpaper on Linux. It seems like I need to use dbus and JS to do that in KDE and I'm a bit confused about it.
 I found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215899), and tried running `qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript ~/scripts/wallpaper.js`, where `wallpaper.js` is as follows:

```
var allDesktops = desktops();
print (allDesktops);

for (i=0;i<allDesktops.length;i++) {
    d = allDesktops[i];
    d.wallpaperPlugin = "org.kde.image";
    d.currentConfigGroup = Array("Wallpaper", "org.kde.image", "General");
    d.writeConfig("Image", "file:///home/amino/Pictures/wallpapers/wallhaven-360156.jpg")
}
```

But I get this error:
`Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid regular expression`

Is there a better way to do this? If not, what would be the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The fastest way is the `kwriteconfig` or `kwriteconfig5` command-line tool. I don't use KDE, so can't tell if it works. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/839647/gsettings-like-tools-for-kde)

Answer (score 2):

This is my first time answering a question on here, so apologies if it's not quite right.
I believe the only thing that might be wrong with your JS code is perhaps it needs additional single quotes and maybe adding 'file://' is unnecessary.

```
- d.writeConfig("Image", "file:///home/amino/Pictures/wallpapers/wallhaven-360156.jpg")
+ d.writeConfig("Image", "'file:///home/amino/Pictures/wallpapers/wallhaven-360156.jpg'")
```

For additional info this is the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
WALLPAPERDIR="/pathtodir/"

qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript 'var allDesktops = desktops();

print (allDesktops);for (i=0;i<allDesktops.length;i++) {
d = allDesktops[i];d.wallpaperPlugin = "org.kde.slideshow";
d.currentConfigGroup = Array("Wallpaper", "org.kde.slideshow", "General");
d.writeConfig("SlidePaths", "'${WALLPAPERDIR}'")}'
```

This works absolutely flawlessly.